# Why are MOSFETs connected in reverse for synchronous rectification?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier

I'm trying to understand how synchronous rectification works.

Here is an example in boost topology:

[image]

The function of `D1` is to allow current from left to right and block right to left.

`M3` is a PMOSFET which conducts from source to drain when the gate is driven on. <s>The conduction direction is from right to left which is the opposite to the diode.</s>

From what I understand, the MOSFET has body diode that conducts in reverse of the channel direction, and the body diode cannot be turned off. The body diode has much worse performance than a power Schottky diode in terms of forward voltage and recovery time.

Does synchronous rectification just use the body diode of `M3` to replace the `D1`? If so, why bother driving the gate of `M3` since the body diode cannot be controlled by the gate anyway?

When `M3` is driven on, the channel allows current flow from right to left, which is undesirable, so again why bother driving the gate of `M3`?

The whole point of synchronous rectification is to avoid forward voltage. I don't see how that could happen when the <s>MOSFET conduction direction is in the opposite direction of the rectifier</s>.

**Answer: Misconception about MOSFET**

```
False: MOSFET conducts only in the charge carrier direction (S->D for P cahnnel, D->S for N channel)
```

```
True: MOSFET conducts in both directions, and behave like a resistor with R = Rds(on) when fully driven.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Why MOSFET are connected in reverse for synchronous rectification?*

MOSFETs have an internal bulk diode that is usually wired to the source and, it makes the synchronous **boost** circuit become this: -

[image]

It's pretty much the same as **your** asynchronous **boost** circuit but, the diode can be "shorted" out by the p-channel MOSFET and yes, MOSFETs do conduct in reverse when activated by the appropriate gate-source voltage. [4 quadrant MOSFET operation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533880/synchronous-buck-nmos-current-flow-direction/533881#533881): -

[image]

And, of course, it's quite often an n-channel MOSFET that is used for both devices: -

[image]

Comment: So the body diode only behave like a diode when the gate is fully closed? When gate is open the body diode behave like a resistor?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "fully-closed" in this context. Ditto "When gate is open" @7E10FC9A. The gate is either activated with sufficient voltage with respect to the source to obtain triode conduction (i.e. the channel's "on" or fully conducting) or it's not activated i.e. has 0 volts or a negative voltage with respect to source.

Comment: @7E10FC9A The body diode always behaves like a diode, it is a diode. When the FET is conducting, it doesn't matter how the body diode behaves, as it's shorted. When the FET is not conducting, then you can see the diode behaviour (doesn't conduct in one direction, conducts with a forward drop in the other).

Comment: for NMOSFET, fully-closed means Vgs = 0, When gate is open means Vgs>Vgs(th)

Comment: @7E10FC9A that's not how we say it. We say the gate is activated or, the gate is driven by sufficient voltage to achieve triode conduction in the channel. The gate is neither open nor closed; only the channel can be open (open circuit) or closed (like a switch is closed). This applies to n-channel and p-channel MOSFETS equally.

Comment: so my misconception is that MOSFET conducts only in the charge carrier direction (S->D for PMOSFET, D->S for NMOSFET)  instead of both directions?

Comment: The channel will conduct in both directions providing the gate is adequately driven. Usually, the reverse conduction isn't as good as the forward conduction but, it's normally far superior than the forward conduction of the diode up until the point when the lines on the graph cross, then the body diode conducts better.

Comment: To the OP: If "open" and "closed" are confusing, I recommend you say "on" and "off." For us, "open" means no circuit (off) and "closed" means there is a circuit (on).